# How to automatically click on button, every time I visit a web page

Tags: selenium, web

I have a web page that I visit regularly. There is a drop down menu, to select the mode of the page, the default I never use, I always select the 2nd option. 
I then almost always click the button that represents the event at the current time.

How can I configure my browser to do these clicks for me.

---

What I am looking for is not a finished solution, but some advice as to whether selenium is the way to go.

Do I need an external language, or just the built in editor (I think that is a separate extension)?

Do/can I leave this server running while I am surfing, and it kicks in when I surf to the page?

Comment: By writing some code :) Could you elaborate more? Provide the code you have so far, the link to the web-site (if possible) or the HTML code of the page or relevant tags. What selenium language bindings are you using?

Comment: Note: Selenium WebDriver does not officially support attaching to existing browser windows. You'd have to get Selenium to start the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Selenium IDE, which is a GUI-based application that enables you to "record" your actions on a given webpage; after you have recorded your actions, next time, simply fireup Selenium IDE and "play" you recorded actions.
http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Or,

You can write a script using selenium webdriver, I personally recommend you to use Python with Selenium webdriver.
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to automate a web browser. Here are three of them:

- Selenium: Allows a program to automate a browser (e.g. Java telling Firefox what to do)
- PhantomJS: A "headless" browser that is automated through a Javascript file
- GreaseMonkey: A Firefox plugin which injects your own Javascript into a page which was loaded from a web server that you do not control

These generally serve different sets of use cases. Your purpose sounds a lot like what I use GreaseMonkey for - repeating a task that I always do on a system. An example of this would be automatically logging in when you arrive at a certain page. For example, this GM script will fill in the name and password blanks and click the submit button when a certain page is visited:

```
$("#username").val("myuser");
$("#password").val("a2t4w3a1j6");
$("#signinbtn").trigger('click');
```

You mention Selenium as a possible solution. I don't think that is the way to go. Selenium's main use is to run as part of a testing framework and check that a web system is working properly given a particular set of inputs. It will start up the browser itself and close it when the test is complete. If you just need to streamline the work you do in a browser, you will probably find GreaseMonkey to be your best tool.

Comment: Selenium did not feel right, to me either. Hence my question, I will try GreaseMonkey next time.